# Adding function parameters creates variable shadowing, while no parameters result in reassignment?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, shadowing

Below I have 2 examples, with the only difference being that one function has a parameter while the other doesn't. But Example 1 will log `hello` to the console, while Example 2 logs `hello!` to the console.

My question is why does Example 1 log `hello` while Example 2 logs `hello!`.

Example 1, I'm uncertain of whats going on. My guess is that in Example 1 we are using variable shadowing. The `greet` parameter is is initialized to a primitive string `hello`. The `greet` parameter are shadowing the `greet` from line 1. Therefore when we log `greet` to the console we are logging  the `greet` from the global scope, `hello`.

I'm not positive but, in Example 2, the function `salutation` is invoked with the argument `'hello'`. Then the global variable `greet` is reassigned to the value of `'hello' + '!'`. Therefore when `greet` is logged to the console, we are  logging the value that `greet` was reassigned to, `hello!`.

*Why does the lack of a `greet` parameter in the function allow us to log the reassigned value to the console. But when the function has a parameter we log the global variable to the console?*

**Example 1.**

```js
let greet = 'hello';

function salutation(greet) {
    greet = greet + '!';
}

salutation(greet);
console.log(greet); //hello
```

**Example 2.**

```js
let greet = 'hello';

function salutation() {
    greet = greet + '!';
}

salutation(greet);
console.log(greet); //'hello!'
```

Comment: How about giving this answer a read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/1563833

Answer (score 1):

The **argument to the function is copied by value**, so the `greet` (global) and the `greet` (local) are completely different. With the below line `greet` is a copy of the global variable and is only available inside the function, hence local.

```
function salutation(greet) {
    greet = greet + '!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the lack of a `greet` parameter in the function allow us to log the reassigned value to the console. But when the function has a parameter we log the global variable to the console?

*Both* examples do log the global variable to the console.

It's just that in the first snippet, there is a local `greet` variable that gets reassigned, while in the second snippet there is no local variable and it assigns (and accesses) the global variable `greet` through closure.